# Open port 8140 in iptables to enable Puppet to work in centos 5

Tags: centos, iptables

Here is the output of iptables -L

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
RH-Firewall-1-INPUT  all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
RH-Firewall-1-INPUT  all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain RH-Firewall-1-INPUT (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            icmp any
ACCEPT     esp  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     ah   --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             224.0.0.251         udp dpt:mdns
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:ipp
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:ipp
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:ssh
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
```

I want to open port 8140 so other puppet clients can communicate with the puppet master, so I tried adding this rule:

```
iptables -I INPUT 2 -p tcp --dport 8140 -j ACCEPT
```

But it didn't work.  If it helps, the output of iptables-save is

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.3.5 on Mon Jun 21 17:07:33 2010
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [605:28389]
:RH-Firewall-1-INPUT - [0:0]
-A INPUT -j RH-Firewall-1-INPUT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8140 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -j RH-Firewall-1-INPUT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type any -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p esp -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p ah -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -d 224.0.0.251 -p udp -m udp --dport 5353 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 631 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 631 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
COMMIT
# Completed on Mon Jun 21 17:07:33 2010
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you were to add

```
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8140 -j ACCEPT
```

Just before the line that reads:

```
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

That should give you the desired result you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the chain named RH-Firewall-1, not INPUT.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use system-config-security (or something like that) to modify the firewall rules. This is preferred as it is persistent and survives reboots of the server.

Comment: Yes, using the system-config-security is convenient but it is not generally universal between Linux systems; whereas knowing the proper way to edit the file format iptables reads is and it still survives the reboots. Having a tool and having the knowledge are two different things that an admin should have.

Comment: Completely agree. Though as the question stated CentOS/RedHat it is better to use their tools unless you are doing something really funky.

Comment: Though if you've been building servers like I do those little extra packages are not installed as they are pointless for someone that knows how to do it without them. I run stripped down installations on all my systems so only what is absolutely necessary to do the task the server is assigned are installed.